# Java GPA calculation (how to set unlimited arrays?)

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Basically, my problem is that I am not sure on how to set unlimited input arrays from user.. 
For now, the calculation only goes well if the user enters 6 subject exactly, but not if entered subject is less or more than 6..
Somehow, i want to make the input to be unlimited..

This is what I have so far:

**THE MAIN CLASS**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CGPAMain extends JFrame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GPA Calculation");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MainPage panel = new MainPage();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**THE OTHER CLASS**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MainPage extends JPanel
    {
        //declare GUI elements
        private JLabel subjectLabel, cHoursLabel, gradeLabel;       
        private JTextField subject, cHours;
        private JButton addSubjectButton, calcGPAButton, clearAllButton;
        private JTextArea tArea;
        private JComboBox grade;

        //declare array to store and collect user input value
        String[] subjectArray = new String[6];                  
        String[] gradeArray = new String[6];
        int[] cHoursArray = new int[6];
        double[] gradeValue = { 4.00, 3.67, 3.33, 3.00, 2.67, 2.33, 2.00, 1.67, 1.33, 1.00, 0.00 };
        String[] gradeLetter= { "A",  "A-", "B+", "B",  "B-", "C+", "C",  "D",  "D-", "E",  "F"};                  


        public MainPage()
        {   
            setLayout (null);
            setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 500));
            setBackground (Color.orange); 

            //Properties of GUI elements
            subjectLabel = new JLabel ("Subject Name: ");                       
            subject = new JTextField (33);
            subject.addActionListener (new TempListener());

            gradeLabel = new JLabel ("Grade: ");
            grade = new JComboBox (gradeLetter); 
            grade.addActionListener (new TempListener());

            cHoursLabel = new JLabel ("Credit Hours: ");
            cHours = new JTextField (1);
            cHours.addActionListener (new TempListener());

            addSubjectButton = new JButton("Add Another Subject");
            addSubjectButton.addActionListener(new TempListener());
            calcGPAButton = new JButton("Calculate GPA");
            calcGPAButton.addActionListener(new TempListener());
            clearAllButton = new JButton("Clear All");
            clearAllButton.addActionListener(new TempListener());

            tArea = new JTextArea(5, 5);                
            tArea.setEditable(false);     

            add (subjectLabel);
            add (subject);
            add (gradeLabel);
            add (grade);
            add (cHoursLabel);
            add (cHours);
            add (addSubjectButton);
            add (calcGPAButton);
            add (clearAllButton);
            add (tArea);

            //Position of GUI elements
            subjectLabel.setBounds      (20, 20, 150, 20);              
            subject.setBounds           (120, 20, 350, 20);
            gradeLabel.setBounds        (20, 50, 50, 20);
            grade.setBounds             (120, 50, 50, 20);
            cHoursLabel.setBounds       (20, 80, 100, 20);
            cHours.setBounds            (120, 80, 50, 20);
            addSubjectButton.setBounds  (20, 120, 200, 30);
            calcGPAButton.setBounds     (300, 440, 175, 30);
            clearAllButton.setBounds    (20, 440, 120, 30);
            tArea.setBounds             (20, 170, 450, 250); 
        }


        private class TempListener implements ActionListener
        {
          //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
          //  Performs the conversion when the enter key is pressed in the text field.
          //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            double tCrPoints = 0.00, tCrHours = 0.00, tGPA = 0.00;  
            String status; 

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getSource() == addSubjectButton)                   
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
                    {
                        subjectArray[i] = subject.getText();
                        gradeArray[i] = (String) grade.getSelectedItem();
                        cHoursArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(cHours.getText()); 
                    }

                    tArea.append (subject.getText() + "\t\t\t" + 
                                  grade.getSelectedItem() + "\t"  + 
                                  cHours.getText() + "\n"); 
                    subject.setText("");
                    cHours.setText(""); 
                }


                if (event.getSource() == calcGPAButton)   
                {
                    for (int i=0 ; i<gradeArray.length; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j=0; j<gradeLetter.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(gradeArray[i].equals(gradeLetter[j]))
                            {
                                tCrHours += cHoursArray[i]; 
                                tCrPoints += gradeValue[j] * cHoursArray[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    tGPA = tCrPoints/tCrHours;

                    if (tGPA >= 2)
                        status = ("Pass");
                    else
                        status = ("Fail"); 

                    //Output for text area 
                    tArea.setText("Total Credit Points : " + tCrPoints + "\n" +
                                  "Total Credit Hours : " + tCrHours + "\n\n" + 
                                  "Grade Point Average (GPA) : " + tGPA + "\n" +
                                  "Status : " + status); 
                } 


                if (event.getSource() == clearAllButton)  
                {
                    tArea.setText("");
                    cHours.setText("");
                    grade.setSelectedIndex(0);
                    tCrHours = 0.00;
                    tCrPoints = 0.00;
                }


           }





        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 3):

You did a good job splitting apart the `main()` from the GUI and the rest of the application, but I think you should have taken it further to split the GUI from the calculation code, too.

Consider the larger question: Why does a GUI `JPanel` know about grades and GPAs? The job of a `JPanel` is to know how to render GUI elements within a box and route input events to the right widget object.

I believe your code would be far more maintainable and definitely more malleable if you split the code to manage the grades from the code to handle the GUI. There's always going to be a bit of a rough edge between telling the GUI to update values into the [model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) vs having the model poll the data values from the GUI, but you can define that interface to suit your needs best: it might be a `GPA` object that uses [SLaks's recommended `ArrayList<E>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8627712/377270) to store individual `Subject` objects that know the name, grade, dates the course was conducted, etc. (It might just be (`name`, `grade`) tuples, since this is short and sweet so far.)

Your `GPA` object could export an interface: `public void addSubject(String className, String grade)` and `public double getGPA()`. Your GUI could call into this interface to add new classes and retrieve the GPA for display.

I realize that this is a much more drastic re-write than you were looking for. And it doesn't even immediately address your concern. But I believe the GPA code, when viewed on its own, would look far more easily manipulated than it currently does buried amongst the GUI code.

Comment: If you're under a deadline and don't have time to re-write your code as I've suggested -- or otherwise don't want to -- you'll need to re-write your code using the [`ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) collection, or another mechanism as suggested by [Óscar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8627727/377270).

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) or even [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for the functionality you seek. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234) explaining how to use an `ArrayList`.

The idea is simple: the `ArrayList` will take care of growing an internal array for storing its elements, and as you keep adding elements to it, it will keep growing automatically to accommodate them. Strictly speaking, the size won't be *unlimited*, but a maximum of 2^31-1 positions (assuming that you have enough memory) should me more than enough for most practical cases.

**EDIT :**

For your particular example:

```
// create an ArrayList
ArrayList<Double> gradeValue = new ArrayList<Double>();

// add elements to the ArrayList
gradeValue.add(4.00);
gradeValue.add(3.67); // etc.

// iterating over the ArrayList
for (int i = 0; i < gradeValue.size(); i++) {
    double value = gradeValue.get(i);
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: @AisyahNadiah I added a little sample code, I'll let you figure out the details (take a look at the tutorial!)

Comment: hm..but how to receive input from user for subjectArray, gradeArray and cHoursArray.. it should be that i dont have to set up the element to ArrayList

Comment: Use `ArrayList` _instead_ of arrays, you have to learn to use Collections

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashmap to contain all your grades, and use array lists to contain your hour and grade earned. Here is a quick rewrite of what you have.

```
public class MainPage extends JPanel {

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

private JLabel subjectLabel, cHoursLabel, gradeLabel;      
private JTextField subject, cHours;
private JButton addSubjectButton, calcGPAButton, clearAllButton;
private JTextArea tArea;
private JComboBox grade;

List<String> gradeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> cHoursArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<String, Double> grades = new HashMap<String, Double>();

public MainPage() {
    this.populateGrades();

    setLayout(null);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(500, 500));
    setBackground (Color.orange);

    subjectLabel = new JLabel ("Subject Name: ");
    subject = new JTextField (33);
    subject.addActionListener (new TempListener());

    gradeLabel = new JLabel ("Grade: ");
    grade = new JComboBox (grades.keySet().toArray()); 
    grade.addActionListener (new TempListener());

    // ... THE REST OF YOU CODE ... //
}

private void populateGrades() {
    grades.put("A", 4.00);
    grades.put("A-", 3.67);
    grades.put("B+", 3.67);
    grades.put("B", 3.67);
    grades.put("B-", 3.67);
    grades.put("C+", 3.67);
    grades.put("C", 3.67);
    grades.put("D", 3.67);
    grades.put("D-", 3.67);
    grades.put("E", 3.67);
    grades.put("F", 3.67);
}

private class TempListener implements ActionListener {
    double tCrPoints = 0.00, tCrHours = 0.00, tGPA = 0.00;
    String status;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == addSubjectButton) {
            // Not sure what you are trying to do here, you are basically setting the 3 arrays identical
            // subject.getText() = 1 ==> subjectArray[1,1,1,1,1,1]
            // Do not see the point of this at all
            /* for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
                subjectArray[i] = subject.getText();
                gradeArray[i] = (String) grade.getSelectedItem();
                cHoursArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(cHours.getText());
            } */

            gradeArray.add(grade.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cHoursArray.add(Integer.parseInt(cHours.getText()));

            tArea.append (subject.getText() + "\t\t\t" + grade.getSelectedItem() + "\t"  + cHours.getText() + "\n");
            subject.setText("");
            cHours.setText("");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == calcGPAButton) {
            for (String grade : gradeArray) {
                tCrPoints += grades.get(grade);
            }

            for (Integer hour : cHoursArray) {
                tCrHours += hour;
            }

            tGPA = tCrPoints/tCrHours;

            if (tGPA >= 2) {
                status = ("Pass");
            } else {
                status = ("Fail");
            }

            tArea.setText("Total Credit Points : " + tCrPoints + "\n" +
                        "Total Credit Hours : " + tCrHours + "\n\n" +
                        "Grade Point Average (GPA) : " + tGPA + "\n" +
                        "Status : " + status);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == clearAllButton) {
            tArea.setText("");
            cHours.setText("");
            grade.setSelectedIndex(0);
            tCrHours = 0.00;
            tCrPoints = 0.00;
        }
    }
}
}
```